# Re ordenar barras de un gráfico de ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tengo una data frame de un servicio de bicis, que se ve así

| Viaje_Id | Usuario_Id | Genero | Año_de_nacimiento | Inicio_del_viaje | Fin_del_viaje | Origen_Id | Destino_Id | Edad | Duracion | dia |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14420217 | 451617 | M | 1992 | 2020-01-01 06:02:20 | 2020-01-01 06:05:38 | 52 | 268 | 28 | 3.3000000 | Wednesday |
| 14420218 | 324211 | M | 1985 | 2020-01-01 06:02:22 | 2020-01-01 06:07:32 | 254 | 180 | 35 | 5.1666667 | Wednesday |
| 14420219 | 611633 | M | 1981 | 2020-01-01 06:03:01 | 2020-01-01 06:21:43 | 258 | 278 | 39 | 18.7000000 | Wednesday |

la columna de día yo se la agregue con la siguiente linea de código

```
jan2020$dia <- weekdays(as.Date(jan2020$Inicio_del_viaje))
```

Después quise hacer una visualización con el siguiente código

```
jan2020 %>%
  group_by(dia, Genero) %>%
  summarize(freq = n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = dia, y = freq, fill = freq))  +   
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Genero), stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  xlab("Día") +
  ylab("Frequency") +
  labs(fill = "Genero") +
  theme_fivethirtyeight() + 
  theme(legend.position ='bottom', axis.text.x = element_text(size = 20)) +theme(text = element_text(size=22))+ggtitle("Número de usuarios por día y genero")
```

Y obtuve
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero quisiera que las barras estuvieran en orden como "Monday","Tuesday", etc, ¿hay forma alguna de hacer esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que trabajar la variable del eje x como factor, asi ggplot entiende que existe un orden jerárquico a la hora de graficar, esto se hace con la función factor de r base, u otras como reorder.factor de gdata, etc

Puedes agregar un pipe

```
jan2020 %>%
  group_by(dia, Genero) %>%
  summarize(freq = n()) %>%
  mutate(dia = factor(dia,c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday")))
```

o directamente

```
jan2020$dia = factor(jan2020$dia,c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"))
```

Usando la otra librería anteriormente mencionada seria:

```
jan2020 %>%
      group_by(dia, Genero) %>%
      summarize(freq = n()) %>%
      mutate(dia = reorder.factor(dia, new.order = c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday")))
```

Otra solución, sin tocar la base de datos es agregar la siguiente capa a ggplot:

```
  + scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"))
```